# How to replace "-" with "_" in Vim using regular expressions?

Tags: html, regex, vim, vi

Can you advise me a regexp to replace `-` to `_` in my HTML file but focus on `href` and `src` attributes only (I don't need to make any changes to contents of my Web page).

For instance:

Before:

```
<a href="my-profile.html">PLF Series</a>
<img src="images/my-sample.jpg">
```

After:

```
<a href="my_profile.html">PLF Series</a>
<img src="images/my_sample.jpg">
```

Comment: Almost... here comes [Tony the pony](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1386111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one needs to be repeated until there is no match:

```
%s/\(\(href\|src\) *= *"[^"-]*\)-/\1_/g
```

Comment: I'd say you have the better answer. Same response time. gg.